# NullPointerException - cannot see my issue

Tags: java

Pretty sure this is going to be something woefully silly, but I've been staring at this for a while now and cannot see what I've done wrong.

Messing about with a bit of Gherkin and I have code in a different class (which also calls another class) - I've tried to break this down to the simplest example:

In my @Before I have this:

```
public void setUp() {   
    whoAmI= new MyNameClass();
}
```

I then use this in the following manner:

```
    String myName2 = new String("My name is " + whoAmI.returnJoe());

    System.out.println(myName2);
```

In the MyNameClass I have the following:

```
public static String returnJoe() {
    System.out.println(steps.helloJoe() + " ");
    return "Joe";
}
```

And when I run this - no issues. All is well.

I then change the returnJoe method to this:

```
static WebDriverSteps steps;


public static String returnJoe() {

    return "Joe" + steps.helloJoe();
    System.out.println(steps.helloJoe() + " ");
    return "Joe";
}
```

And WebDriverSteps has the following:

```
public class WebDriverSteps {

    WebDriverSteps steps;

    public String helloJoe() {

        return " what do you know?";
    }
```

Now I get a null pointer.  I am pretty sure my issue is caused by a constructor, but having a silly moment and cannot figure it out.

Anyone see the issue?

Comment: stacktrace will tell you where the problem is

Comment: In `returnJoe` the `steps` object may be null.

Comment: Can you add the full traceback and exception message?

Comment: The stacktrace should point you exactly to the line where the issue is.

Comment: You also have two returns word without any condition statement  in your returnJoe() method

Comment: did you initialize webdriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code above you've forgotten to call the constructor of the class WebDriverSteps. That makes the object steps to point to null. So when you're calling steps.helloJoe() , it returns Null pointer Exception.
The code should've been
     WebDriverSteps steps = new WebDriverSteps();